# How to handle ng- click() with argument in a Protractor

Tags: protractor, angularjs-ng-click

Code line:

```
ng-click="my.Update(Profile)"
```

Now how will I locate this element in protractor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *CSS selector* to locate this element:

```
$('[ng-click="my.Update(Profile)"]');
```

Note that you don't have to check the complete value of the `ng-click` attribute and can use a partial match instead, for instance:

```
$('[ng-click*=Profile]');
$('[ng-click*=Update]');
```

The `$` is a shortcut to `element(by.css())`.